# ArrayList turns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I'm working on a Web app using ASP.NET. I have a class called "Sistema" that uses the Singleton pattern.

When the instance of Sistema is created, the database connection is opened and a process runs that loads some static information into more than one ArrayList for later use.

```
private ArrayList list1;
private ArrayList list2;
private static Sistema instance;
private Sistema()
{
    OpenDataBase();
    list1 = LoadStaticInformationFromDataBase();
    list2 = LoadOtherStaticInformationFromDataBase();
}

public static Sistema GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Sistema();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Throughout the day, new objects are added to each ArrayList. 
During the last couple of days, it has occurred that suddenly one of these ArrayList becomes null, and as consequence, the whole site stops working.

I haven't been able to determine why this becomes null.

Can it be that the ArrayList reaches the maximum amount? For example, right now it has more than 150.000 objects in it.

Inside the Global.asax file, in the Application_Error method, I've added a piece of code that stores in a txt file as a log every error. However, there's no error at that time.

Any suggestions to why is this happening?

Comment: Is this your actual implementation? Because it's not thread safe.. and would explain your issues. I would suggest reading this page by Jon Skeet: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: See the Multithreaded Singleton section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Hi Simon. Thanks for the quick response. I've edited my question. In the Constructor, more than one ArrayList is loaded. However, at some point, only one of this is null, so I guess it's not an issue with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Static fields of a class exist for as long as the ASP.NET worker process lives. As soon as the ASP.NET worker process is recycled, you will lose all static data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not sure if that is the case, because besides ArrayList "list", I load a couple of more ArrayList in the Singleton constructor, and these are OK (not null). Besides, the Session variables are still there. When the worker process is recyled, Session variables are lost too, right?

Comment: That depends on the kind of Session state you use. If you're using SQL Server or Session Server state, then it's outside of the worker process and will live even after the worker process dies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app pool is set to recycle at 3am each day. What might trigger this to recycle at a specific time? However, if the process is recycled, every ArrayList should be null, not just one of them, so I'm not sure if this is the cause..

Comment: The following is certain: _if_ they recycle, then statics will be cleared. The question now is _whether_ there is a recycle.

Comment: Right. I really don't think that is the cause. But I have no clue what might be..